# Calling Linq to SQL method in Web service with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have a test web service called: MySimpleService.svc with a method called:GetUserNamesByInitials. below is the Linq to SQL code:

```
[OperationContract]   
public static string GetUserNamesByInitials(string initials)
{
        string result = "";

        //obtain the data source
        var testDB = new TestDBDataContext();

        //create the query
        var query = from c in testDB.TestTables
                    where c.initials == initials
                    select c;

        //execute the query
        foreach (var c in query)
        {
            result = result + c.full_name;
        }

        return result;
}
```

I have used that code in page behind and it works well. However when i try to call it using jQuery I don't get any result, no errors nothing. below is the code i use in jQuery:

```
$('#TextBox3').live('keydown', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //call function here
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/MySimpleService.svc/GetUserNamesByInitials",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{"word":"' + $('#TextBox3').val() + '"}',
            success: function(data) {

                $('#TextBox4').val(data.d);


            }

        });


    }


});

});
```

what I do is to type the user id in one textbox (TextBox3) and when I press the Tab key the result is shown in another textbox (TextBox4).
The jQuery call works well with other methods that do not call the database, for example using this other web service method it works:

```
[OperationContract]
public string ParameterizedConnectionTest(string word)
{
    return string.Format("You entered the word: {0}", word);    
}
```

However with the Linq method it just does not work. Maybe i am doing something wrong? thank you in advance.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but please use a StringBuilder to assemble the results string. Using the + operator to append is horribly inefficient.

Comment: I am quite sure you need to decorate the method with the `[WebMethod]` attribute, to use it as a page method. Also, you are using `"/MySimpleService.svc/GetUserNamesByInitials"` as the method path: are you sure you need the initial `/`?

Answer (score 1):

The web service is expecting a string named "initials" and you're sending it a string called "word". More than likely it is throwing an exception that it's not being passed the expected parameter.

Try adding an error: function() in your $.ajax() call to catch the error. I would also suggest installing [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to be able to view and debug the AJAX request and response. Here's the updated $.ajax() call with the right parameter name and an error function which should invoke your chosen javascript debugger if you have it open:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "/MySimpleService.svc/GetUserNamesByInitials",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 data: '{"initials":"' + $('#TextBox3').val() + '"}',
 success: function(data) {
  $('#TextBox4').val(data.d);
 },
 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert('Error!');
  debugger; // Will let you see the response in FireBug, IE8 debugger, etc.
 }
});
```

**Update**

So I just noticed that you're using WCF services instead of normal ASP.Net (ASMX) services... Some additional suggestions:

1. Enable [IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedebugbehavior.includeexceptiondetailinfaults.aspx) in your web.config so that you can debug any errors happening. ASP.Net services will return an error by default but you need to explicitly turn this on for WCF.
2. Try adding an additional attribute below your [OperationContract] attribute to specify you're expecting a post with JSON data:

   ```
   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   ```

Comment: thanks for the correction. Yes i have corrected the jQuery string to display "initials" but i still get no response. and when I add the error function to jQuery code it gives me syntax error :(

Comment: Tika: The code was missing a comma. I updated it. Once you know what error is being returned we can be more helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me solve this issue,

The debugger works well now, In the XMLHttpRequest node of the scrip tab in firebug I get some error messages:


get responseXML      Document
  childNodes    [XMLStylesheetProcessingInstruction { baseURI="http://localhost/MySimp.../GetUserNamesByInitials",  more...}, parsererror]
  

  0   XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: http://localhost/MySimpleService.svc/GetUserNamesByInitials Line Number 1, Column 1:      
get status       404
get status text       "Not Found"


errorThrown         undefined
textStatus        "error"

Comment: So you're getting a 404 error which means that the web service being called isn't setup on the server (it's returning "not found" instead of throwing a 500-type exception/error). Can you browse to /MySimpleService.svc and do you get a page with information on the services available?

Comment: Thanks, When i try to browse to it the page shows the message:
This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service.
Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.
with instructions to change the behavior in the web config file.
However i can still use the web service whenever I invoke the ParameterizedConnectionTest method. I am now learning the WCF services and I am not sure if they can be browsed just like the other webservices are.
What I do is create a Website and then add the Ajax-enabled WCF Service. I feel we are getting close to solving this issue.
thank you.